# JPA entity mapping

Tags: java, jpa

A quick summary of what I am trying to achieve. 
Please give suggestions on implementation or design :)

I have two tables:  User, Image.
In UserDO, I want to keep a Set of all user's images, as well as single image which is user's portrait (the set will include portrait in my case):

```
public class UserDO {
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "imageid")
   Set<ImageDO> userimages

   // How to represent this? the foreign key is used for the above mapping
   ImageDO portrait;
   ....
}
```

In ImageDO, I have a userid as foreign key to record which user uploaded the image. But it doesn't have a boolean, because thinking one user may upload many images, but only one is portrait.

Any way could achieve this? or do I need to maintain another table(say, Portrait, containing "userid","portraitid" mapping) ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (and standard) way would be to simply add a @OneToOne annotation to the portrait and then add a column to the UserDO table which is a foreign key into the ImageDO table.